# Why is the Android Camera2 preview not showing. It's a dark scene and the TextureView listener is not getting called on activity launch

Tags: android, android-camera2, textureview

I followed the basic sample code from Google for Android Camera2 API.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.

After I integrated it into my app, it is showing dark scene. No camera output can be seen. It was working fine before integration.

---

Why is the `TextureView` listener not getting triggered? Is there some other issue apart from this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the Java code. It worked after I added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the `CameraActivity` `<activity>` tag in the `Manifest.xml` file.

What I found strange in this solution was that the Camera app worked without this property, but after integrating it into a different app, it didn't.

If anyone has any idea as to why it worked before, but not after integration, kindly share your answer.

```
<activity android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```